# Can I upload two version of the same app on playstore?

Tags: android

Can I upload two version of the same app. Like one is ad free (paid version) and the other one contains ad (free version). Does google play console allows it?

Comment: only if you have different package names...

Comment: In breaf, yes, you can

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, certainly. And it's very easy to if you're using [Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html), as introduced with the Gradle build system.

You should ensure that each app you submit to Google Play has a different, package name, if you're using Flavors you can do this like this:

```
android {  
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.app.free"
        }

        pro {
            applicationId "com.app.full"
        }
    }
}
```

There are [many great tutorials](https://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/) on using Flavors, so it shouln't be to hard to get started too.

*If you're not a big fan of using Gradle, you can of-course maintain two projects with different package names and submit them both to Google Play, but I wouldn't recommend doing so.*

Comment: Thanks... this what i wanted to know

Comment: @ss007 It's not a problem. You can add flavors to your existing project and simply keep using the same package name for the pro version, and add a different package name for the free flavor.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload exactly the same apps on PlayStore if package names are different.